# Failing Travis CI tests when using secret keys in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, travis-ci

I am using environment variables in `secrets.yml` for production environment in my rails app. I am sending http post request with api key and password. I can pass my local tests in test environment by using the password. But my password can't be exposed, so how do I pass travis ci tests on github?

Comment: Maybe [Travis docs](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables/) will help.

Comment: I would argue that you should not make requests to external servers in your tests anyway. Just stub the calls in your tests.

Comment: How do I stub the calls in my tests so that in production I can make the request?

Answer (score 1):

You can encrypt your `secrets.yml` and push encrypted file to the repository.

```
travis encrypt-file secrets.yml
```

which will give you `secrets.yml.enc` add it to repository. Remember not to push `secrets.yml`.

You need to decrypt that file in `before_script`

```
before_script: openssl aes-256-cbc -K $encrypted_0a6446eb3ae3_key -iv $encrypted_0a6446eb3ae3_key -in secrets.yml.enc -out secrets.yml -d
```

You can directly add above command to travis.yml using `--add` option:

```
travis encrypt-file secrets.yml --add
```

Refer this documentation for more details - [Encrypting Files in Travis](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/encrypting-files/)